# Criação relatórios ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, relatório

Preciso criar vários relatórios no meu sistema para exibir os dados na tela e ter opções de exportar para `Excel` e `PDF`, por onde começo? existe algum componente que me ajude nisso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Excel

O melhor componente que encontrei até então chama-se [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [O pacote NuGet dele está aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). [Aqui no site temos algumas perguntas respondidas sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+epplus). Recomendo a leitura delas pra ter ideia de exemplos de implementação.

## PDF

É comum usarem o [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa) porque ele aceita como entrada um HTML e devolve um PDF, mas o Rotativa não funciona em ambientes puramente Web como o Azure.

Buscando alternativas, achei o [RazorPDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF), mas o pacote não recebe atualizações há algum tempo (acho que o autor morreu ou coisa do tipo, porque não responde minhas mensagens nem a de outros usuários), então criei o [RazorPDF2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2) que funciona com todas as funcionalidades do RazorPDF [e junta mais algumas deste outro](https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf).

## Datatables

Ainda dentro do âmbito de exportação, [o Datatables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.datatables) (componente que melhora tabelas baseado em jQuery) possui opções de exportação para PDF e Excel baseadas em Flash. Pode ser uma opção se seu sistema não faz muito uso de interfaces com dispositivos móveis. [A documentação está aqui](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/built-in).

Precisando de mais detalhes como usar, basta fazer novas perguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Já utilizei o [Reporting da Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx), são ótimos componentes, tem a exportação para excel e pdf nativos e não precisa implementar nada para que isso funcione. Contudo... é paga...