# ASP.NET MVC Relatorios em PDF e EXCEL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-excel, pdf, reportviewer

Boa tarde Pessoal,
Gostaria de obter referências sobre melhores ferramentas para gerar relatórios em uma aplicação MVC que me permita exportar o resultado para PDF e EXCEL.

Atualmente, estou criando uma VIEW, preenchendo uma MODEL com o os dados, e possibilitando exportar a view para PDF utilizando o componente ROTATIVA.

Mas achei que esse trabalho é muito moroso, e sinceramente, tenho dúvidas se esta é a melhor maneira de codificar um relatório na estrutura MVC.

Verifiquei as opções neste post:
[Relatórios com Asp.Net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94696/relat%C3%B3rios-com-asp-net-mvc)

Mas nenhuma das alternativas trabalha com excel.

Verifiquei também que ainda é possível utilizar RDLC em MVC, neste link: 
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2013/09/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4.html

Mas não consigo adicionar arquivos RDLC em meu projeto. Não tenho os templates de Report, em meu visual studio.

Já instalei o ReportViewerForMVC em meu projeto, mas continuo sem os templates RDLC.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90331/37440
Dê uma olhada nessa resposta do Cigano

Comment: Obrigado @RenanCarlos mas pelo que pude perceber nesta resposta, utilizando EPPlus e Rotativa, deveria codificar o mesmo relatorio 2 vezes para o mesmo formato. Não existe uma ferramenta unica que me permita gerar um relatorio e exporta-lo para diferentes formatos, como já era feito como era feito com ReportViewer com arquivos RDLC ?